# Send message to other user in Android App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, communication

I am building a game in Android. I have integrated Facebook with it. I want to achieve the following scenario.
Lets say I want to send a gift/any message to another user whom I will be able find in my app as I fave Facebook integrated. The other user will receive the same in the app as well as a notification in Facebook. 
How to do this? Does Facebook have some API or I have to use my cloud storage.
Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to serve a "facebook notification" to another facebook user. But, you can achieve the messaging to another user inside your own app in the following way.

Maintain a list of users and their Android device IDs, GCM IDs on your server. When a user logs in via facebook, you can store their details and these IDs.
Now, if a user sends a message to another user, it can be delivered as a push notification to the other user as you have the GCM ID of the recipient user. All this happens outside facebook. Facebook will be used only for the user to log in and for you to save the user's details in your server's database.

Again, you can send a message to another facebook user in the friend list only if he has also installed the same app on his device. So, the whole concept of integrating the fb friend list is useless here. He can send messages to anyone who has this particular app and is logged in via FB. :) Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ravi. Could you provide any tutorial how to achieve the push notification for user to user. There is a lot in internet. I'm getting confused.

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/   This is a gud one. Do not follow so many tutorials at once. Follow one and then fix any issues coming in between. Implement what is there exactly in the tutorial and then tweak it according to your needs slowly. All the best.

Comment: Thanks Ravi for your help.